# Unable to download CSV after WordPress version update

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

My site was working fine with WordPress version 4.9.8 but after version update to 5.4 function to CSV upload has stopped working. In debug log showing warning **Cannot modify header information - headers already sent** . Please go through the code and help me to resolve this error -

```
<?php if(isset($_GET['process'])){ 
if($_GET['process'] === 'download'){
global $wpdb;
header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=refreshertracker.csv');
ob_end_clean();
$ptp_id = $_GET['topic'];
$pct_nm = $_GET['center'];
if(!empty($pct_nm))
$query = 'select * from wp_refresher_tracker where post_id ='.$ptp_id.' and centre_name = "'.$pct_nm.'"';
else
$query = 'select * from wp_refresher_tracker where post_id ='.$ptp_id;
//echo $query;
$presult = $wpdb->get_results($query);
//print_r($presult);
// create a file pointer connected to the output stream
$output = fopen('php://output', 'w');

// output the column headings
fputcsv($output, array('Sr_no', 'Name', 'EID', 'Center', 'Topic', 'Brand', 'LOB', 'Skill', 'TrainerName', 'Obt_Marks', 'Total_Marks','Score_%', 'ETime','RefDate'));
$cnt = 0;
$refdata = array();
foreach($presult as $prt){
$cnt=$cnt+1;
$refdata['Sr_no']= $cnt;
$refdata['Name']= $prt->name;
$refdata['EID']= $prt->eid;
$refdata['Center']= $prt->centre_name; 
$refdata['Topic']= $prt->topic; 
$refdata['Brand']= $prt->brand; 
$refdata['LOB']= $prt->lob; 
$refdata['Skill']= $prt->skill; 
$refdata['TrainerName']= $prt->trainer; 
$refdata['Obt_Marks']= $prt->obt_marks; 
$refdata['Total_Marks']= $prt->total_marks; 
$refdata['Score_%'] = round(($prt->obt_marks/$prt->total_marks)*100,2)." %";
$refdata['Time']= $prt->etime; 
$refdata['RefDate']= $prt->Post_Pub_Date;; 
//print_r($refdata);
fputcsv($output, $refdata);
}
fclose($output);
exit;
}}?>
```

Please help as I am unable to find the problem.

Comment: Not super familiar with Wordpress but the error indicates their is an "echo" or something similar before your `header` command or a `header` command. I have run into this in other systems by accidentally placing text before the `<?php` tag because I missed the ctl key or something in a hot-key sequence.  With wordpress one of the updated libraries or the template itself may have an echo or raw character outputting before processing the content generation. Step one is to remove your headers and see if the page starts working without them. The error is probably not in the code you pasted here.

Comment: @danielson317 No, it is not like that, because similar codes (different data set ) are applied at several places in my project and after version upgrade it is not working at everywhere.

Comment: That just reinforces my point. The problem is probably not in the code you included here. Wordpress extensions are open source. If one of the extensions you updated had a bug in it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found a trick to solve this problem. Posting this here, may it could help someone else-

1. Creating the file at "theme-name/temp" folder (manage permission in case of problem )-

```
    $filename = time().'_readerlist.csv';       
    $output = fopen('/var/www/html/wp-content/themes/theme-name/temp/'.$filename, 'w');
```

2. After fputcsv() and exit -  added code/script to download like this

```
    fputcsv(array, string);
    fclose($output);

    $url=site_url().'/wp-content/themes/theme-name/temp/'.$filename;
    echo '<script>download("'.$url.'", "mylist.csv");</script>';
```

3. Added below script in header of page

```
    <script>
    function download(dataurl, filename) {
      var a = document.createElement("a");
      a.href = dataurl;
      a.setAttribute("download", filename);
      a.click();
    }
    </script>
```

Hope this approach may help you.